# How can I compile a ReactJS application (files) into one index.html file?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, compilation, babeljs, jsx

I'm in the process of utilizing ReactJS (JSX) within a microsoft sharepoint static website. This website cannot compile JSX code. As a result, I need to convert my reactjs code/package/app into one simple file that should contain all the code and the dependencies as CDNs: index.html

I've followed the following steps of implementing ReactJS (based on [this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ke90Tje7VS0&t=1206s))

1. [Download NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/)
2. Install create-react-app package:

   `sudo npm i -g create-react-app`
3. Create React Application

   `create-react-app react-app`

After completing my application, my file/directory structure is as follows:

[image: React Application Files and Directories]

**How can I compile this entire application into one simple compiled index.html file that I can utilize in any browser without node.js?**

I've tried the following:

1. I've copied and pasted my index.js code into online [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/), but this tool doesnt create the index.html file I need
2. Followed [Babel Installation Instructions](https://babeljs.io/setup#installation)

   2.1) Ran the following command in the shell

   `npm install --save-dev babel-core`

   2.3) I'm not sure where to put the following javascript command

   ```
   `require("babel-core").transform("code", options);`
   ```
3. [Followed Babel Alternative Installation Instructions](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/usage)

   3.1 Run the following commands in shell

   npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-env
   npm install --save @babel/polyfill

   3.2 Created a config file named babel.config.js in roof of project with this content

   const presets = [
     [
       "@babel/env",
       {
         targets: {
           edge: "17",
           firefox: "60",
           chrome: "67",
           safari: "11.1",
         },
         useBuiltIns: "usage",
       },
     ],
   ];

   module.exports = { presets };

[image]

3.3 However, the following command does not work

```
./node_modules/.bin/babel src --out-dir lib
```

Error:

`-bash: ./node_modules/.bin/babel: No such file or directory`

Comment: Q: Have you considered using Webpack to "compile" your ReactJS app: https://medium.com/@siddharthac6/getting-started-with-react-js-using-webpack-and-babel-66549f8fbcb8

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve that by not creating the project from command line tools.
Try including the react files from cdn via script tag

https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#step-2-add-the-script-tags

You might need to change a few things to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You're using create-react-app and `yarn build` is not what you want to achieve?

Comment: he will need a web server to serves the content of the build folder, because there will be some `script` tags inserted inside index.html. I think the OP want to have all his app package inside a single file called `index.html` in order to launch it without `node.js`